# Is it possible to create an Array of Collections in VB.net or is it bad practice? What other replacements with the same function exist?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections

I am creating an app that has to create controls with specific parameters (some of which are custom parameters used for other applications) so the original method was like this

```
PSEDO CODE(kinda)
Dim ControlType1Color() as color
Dim ControlType1Name() as string
Dim ControlType1Parameter() as string
...
Dim ControlType2Color() as color
...
```

However when implementing that notation it ends up causing me to do quite a few test statements in order to recognize which type of control it is, Then find the correct variable to use. Which is honestly a waste of code space which could be saved.

While I was researching for something similar to java Objects (i believe?) I came across collections which should be what I need. However I need to know how I can implement it for this? Does a collection have infinite length? Can you use it as an array? And can you nest it with an array so you have an Array of Collections or is that just unnecessary?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:

I am trying to record my controls that I created in run-time basically and try to use a single variable to record all Data

Lets say I have  two textboxes and one button

My "Array of Collections" or whatever it would be would be like

```
AoC(0).Color = color
AoC(0).Type = Textbox
AoC(0).ID = ID
Aoc(1).Type = Textbox
...
Aoc(2).Type = Button
...
```

So if I needed to change anything I just change this thing only. I can handle the actual changes in code, I just need to know how to store it in the memory without using 5-15 variables needlessly.

Comment: What is an "Array of Constructs"?

Comment: Typo, Array of collections.

Comment: An array of collections is fine to create - that would be like `List(Of Integer)(5)` which would give you an array of 5 lists of integers.

Comment: Would that be good practice though? Especially for the example I provided

Comment: Firstly, are you suggesting defining a type with `Color`, 'Name' and 'Parameter` properties?  If not, it really looks like you should be.  Are you then suggesting creating multiple collections of items of that type and then storing a specific number of those collections in an array?  That sounds fine in principle but I don't think you've really described your situation sufficiently for us to determine whether that's the best option.

Comment: There are various types of collections to handle various situations but the `List(Of T)` is basically a dynamic array, i.e. it behaves much like an array but can be resized at will.  It can't be used AS an array but it can be used in the same way as an array is in many cases, e.g. getting and setting items by index.  In cases that you specifically need an array, of which there are some, you can call `ToArray` on the collection to generate a new array.

Comment: I will re-write the question to clarify

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle - After your edit I would say that you have "an array of a structure". It's not a collection.

Comment: Hm, That is why I asked my question. I am still unsure of which one I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
Private Structure ControlDetail  
    Public Color As System.Drawing.Color  
    Public ControlType As Type  
    Public ID As String
End Structure
```

Then you can define your data as:

```
Dim Aoc = New ControlDetail() _
{ _
    New ControlDetail() With { .Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red, .ControlType = GetType(TextBox), .ID = "txtFoo1" }, _
    New ControlDetail() With { .Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue, .ControlType = GetType(Button), .ID = "butFoo2" } _
}
```

Then you can get access to the data as `Aoc(0).ID`, for example.